# UIPanGestureRecognizer to pull down UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

Very similar to composing a new mail in the stock iOS mail app, I am constructing my own pull-down view:

[image]

I have the pan gesture added to TableViewController.view from the ContainerViewController. This works fine except when the TableView's content is too tall and has to scroll. Then, my original pan gesture is completely ignored.

I am trying to get the behavior similar to the iOS pull-down modal view.

---

### UPDATED

```
class CotainerViewController: UIViewController {

 ...    

    func viewDidLoad() {

       self.addChild(self.tableViewController)
       tableViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
       self.tableViewController.delegate = self
       self.view.addSubview(self.tableViewController.view)
    
       self.panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
       self.panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
       self.panGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = true
       self.panGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.handlePanGesture(gestureRecognizer:)))        self.tableViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.panGestureRecognizer)
    

    }
```

Comment: *"...behavior similar to the iOS pull-down modal view"* -- as far as I can tell, unless you can describe the issue better... that ***is*** the behavior. You start out with *"similar to composing a new mail"* ... well, when I do that, and type enough in the body so it needs to scroll, that's exactly what happens. What are you trying to do differently?

Comment: @DonMag so, if the table view is short with few cells where it doesn’t have to scroll, what I have works fine. Pan gesture added to view gets recognized and the user can pull it down to dismiss.  The issue is, when the table view is too tall, where it has to scroll, my only feature completely gets ignored.

Comment: Are you *presenting* the table view? Or is it a subview of some other view? You need to show some code of how you're approaching this.

Comment: @DonMag presenting TableViewController.  Adding the on feature to tableViewController.view

Comment: A *presented* controller has built-in "drag down to dismiss" functionality ... are you doing something with your own pan gesture to override that?

Comment: @DonMag not presenting it modally. I will add the code soon.